# Detecting tablet mode on a Thinkpad Yoga 11e

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, tablet

I have a Yoga 11e (the Thinkpad model, not the Chromebook) running Ubuntu 17.04.  The touchscreen works great, which was my biggest concern when first installing Ubuntu, but now I've run into a problem: the keyboard remains active when in tablet mode, which means that simply holding the device, or setting it down, can result in unintended keypresses.

I was hoping I could arrange for a script to run when entering/leaving tablet mode that would disable the keyboard, but I haven't been able to figure out how to detect that mode change.

I found some suggestions online that other Yoga models deliver specific keycode events when in tablet mode, but that doesn't appear to be the case here.  In fact, looking at all the available input devices there don't appear to be any events associated with converting between tablet and laptop mode.  I used the following code to check the input events:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import evdev
from selectors import DefaultSelector, EVENT_READ

selector = DefaultSelector()

for dev in evdev.list_devices():
    selector.register(evdev.InputDevice(dev), EVENT_READ)

while True:
    for key, mask in selector.select():
        device = key.fileobj
        for event in device.read():
            print(key, event)
```

I've also looked at the ACPI events available via acpi_listen, but it looks like this tool itself is really just another view into the input subsystem.

Are you aware of any way to detect if a Yoga 11e changes to tablet mode?

**Update 1**

Venturing further afield, after looking at the source for the `thinkpad_acpi` module and disassembling the ACPI `DSDT` table, it looks as if (a) the `thinkpad_acpi` module relies on an ACPI method named `MHKG` to determine the tablet state, and (b) in the `DSDT` table from the Yoga 11e this method appears to be a no-op.  However, I know nothing about ACPI, so maybe I'm not reading that correctly...and even if I am, I'm not sure what to do next.